# Android - how to put this in for loop

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

Im making a app in which I have 18 buttons (bAnswer1 to bAnswer18) and 6 textviews (tvAnswer1 to 6). My meaning is to slice 6 words in 3 words of 2 (like button, bu - tt - on) I did that with 6 words and each put them in a slice (slice1 to 18)  so this code will repeat itself to case R.id.bAnswer18: and you guys will notice it will be hugh!! I know i can make it really simple by just adding a for loop but it wont work and I cant get out?!

Can someone please help me out of this one??

My code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.bAnswer1:

        if (testing1 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer1.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer1.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        }
        if (testing2 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer2.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer2.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing3 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer3.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer3.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing4 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer4.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer4.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing5 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer5.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer5.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing6 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer6.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer6.setText(old + slice1);
            bAnswer1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }

        break;
    case R.id.bAnswer2:
        if (testing1 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer1.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer1.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;

        }
        if (testing2 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer2.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer2.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing3 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer3.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer3.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing4 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer4.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer4.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing5 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer5.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer5.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        if (testing6 != 6) {
            String old = tvAnswer6.getText().toString();
            tvAnswer6.setText(old + slice2);
            bAnswer2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Just put a for-loop around it. As you said, you already know how to make it simple, so just make it simple.

Comment: You should have an array of buttons and another array of textviews instead of 6 or 18 fields. The rest will be trivial.

Comment: Show us your FOR loop - that's what is broken and you need help with

Answer (score 0):

The real answer you're looking for isn't really in a for-loop.

The for-loop will help if you do this

```
 OnClickListener myOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
 //privately paste what you had
 public void onClick(View v) {
 if (testing1 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer1.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer1.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;

    }
    if (testing2 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer2.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer2.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
    if (testing3 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer3.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer3.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
    if (testing4 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer4.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer4.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
    if (testing5 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer5.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer5.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
    if (testing6 != 6) {
        String old = tvAnswer6.getText().toString();
        tvAnswer6.setText(old + slice1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }});


 Button[] answerButtons = new Button[18];

 for(Button answer : answerButtons)
     answer.setOnClickListener(myOnClick);
```

Remember, don't implement OnClickListener with your Activity, let the views themselves handle it, unless you really need to handle/dispatch onClicks yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your time! But im not that far in the Android scene, What I see is you're making a onclickListener and you put all the 18 button in there so I dont have to use the cases anymore?

Comment: other thing is the use of `break;` why dont use `else if`? and if that are all your cases you can move out v.setVisibility(View.GONE); from the if clauses.

Comment: Y I allready saw that one haha, but still stuck on same question

Comment: I define a local OnClickListener, and then assign the same onClickListener to every button. The functionality will depend on the button being hit, but in essence the same thing will happen for every button.